# Increase performance of the android layout file

Tags: android, performance, layout, android-databinding

I am trying to increase the performance of my layout.

However I could not be able to increase more.

[image]

As you can see in here, `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` takes too long.

This is the full line;

```
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MediaPlayerActivity.this, R.layout.activity_media_player);
```

And this is the **layout file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="br.com.gomus.androidapp.presentation.main.MediaPlayerViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:mContext="br.com.gomus.androidapp.ui.main.MediaPlayerActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragmentContainer"

            />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomPlayer"
            />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomPlayer"
            layout="@layout/bottom_player"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:viewModel="@{viewModel}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragmentContainer"


            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

This is the **bottom_player.xml** that I inflate at the end of the activity_media_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="br.com.gomus.androidapp.presentation.main.MediaPlayerViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.bottomPlayerVisibility}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/playerSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:foreground="@drawable/song_selector"
            android:max="1000"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/playPauseBottom"
            android:onProgressChanged="@{viewModel::onProgressChanged}"
            android:progress="@{viewModel.seekBarPosition}"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/blue_grey"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:removePadding="@{true}" />


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/playerSeekBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songTitle"
                style="@style/TitleTextBottomPlayer"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="@{viewModel.bottomPlayerTitle}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/openMusicPlayer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/playPauseBottom"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="Nothing's Gonna Change the Way You Feel about me now" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/SubTitleTextBottomPlayer"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@{viewModel.bottomPlayerArtist}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/openMusicPlayer"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/playPauseBottom"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/songTitle"
                tools:text="Nothing's Gonna Change" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playPauseBottom"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_player_selector"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:nextFocusRight="@id/openMusicPlayer"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/playerSeekBar"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.openPlayer()}"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back_playlist"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/openMusicPlayer"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_player_selector"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@id/playPauseBottom"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/playerSeekBar"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.playPause()}"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@{viewModel.playing ? @drawable/ic_pause_pequeno : @drawable/ic_play_pequeno}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_play_pequeno" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: you can try to inflate bottomPlayer only when it is nessasary

Comment: If I make the visibility of it as gone, would that help?

Comment: No, GONE visibility still inflates the view just it is invisible and other views not seeing its bounds. Please post code of bottomPlayer

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have updated my post. I think the problem may the seekbar right?

Comment: @AntonisRadz I am trying to inflate it programmatically. I can inflate it, but how can I take back the inflate when I do not need it? Should I use something like remove from parent view? Thanks

Comment: see the answer below. It does not seem that you are using "heavy" layouts, but still you should flatten it want to have faster inflate process.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to make layout flat and put everything in to `ConstraintLayout`.

Other thing is check all the `ImageView` background resources so they would not be to large, if you need `24dp` width image then use not larger than `24dp`width image, if you want different size for different screen then add different folder to your resources with `....-screen size`

also `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` line should be one level up in `ConstraintLayout` not in `<layout`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have changed my layout so that every view is in one `ConstraintLayout`. I also placed the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` line inside of the `ConstraintLayout`. Also my resource files are inside of the appropriate folders. But there is a method `onChangeTime` which updates the position of the seekbar for each second which I thought could be the problem. I added those lines that are under that method into an AsyncTask but still the same issue exists.